# Is there any elementary function whose antiderivative contains an exact constant?

Tags: calculus, integration

Let's say we have $F(x) = \int{f(t)}\ dt$. Now it's obvious to me why $F$ is the class of functions whose derivative yields $f(x)$. However, I was curious if it is possible for the antiderivative to be something such as $F(x) = \tan(x)+5+C$ as an example. I can see how we would merge this to become just $F(x) = \tan(x) + C$ but I'm wondering if it is possible for an elementary antiderivative to contain a constant that the entire class of antiderivatives share. My feeling is that this would never happen but I can't seem to figure out exactly why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No function at all has an antiderivative that contains an exact constant.  This is because if you add a constant to a function, no matter what it is, the function's derivative does not change, since $(f(x)+g(x))' = f'(x) + g'(x$) and the derivative of any constant is identically zero.